# errors: `unknown mutation type: setLoggedIn` & `unknown local mutation type: setLoggedIn, global type: auth/setLoggedIn`

Tags: vue.js, vuex

two errors help me build with vuex modules

errors: `unknown mutation type: setLoggedIn` & `unknown local mutation type: setLoggedIn, global type: auth/setLoggedIn`

vuex version "vuex": "^4.0.0"

the problem occurs in the setLoggedInState(ctx) function

**index.js**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import middleware from "./modules/middleware.js";
import auth from "./modules/auth";


export default new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    modules: {
        auth,
        middleware
    }
})
```

**auth.js**

```
const state = {
    isLoggedIn: true,
};
const mutation = {
    setLoggedIn(state, payload, ) {
        state.isLoggedIn = payload;
    },
};
const actions = {
   setLoggedInState(ctx) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
                    ctx.commit('setLoggedIn', true, {root: true});
                    resolve(true)
                } else  {
                    ctx.commit('setLoggedIn', false, {root: true});
                    resolve(false)
                }
            });
        },
}
const getters = {
    loggedIn(state) {
        return state.isLoggedIn;
    },

   export default {
          namespaced: true,
          state,
          mutation,
          actions,
          getters
    }
```

**Dashboard**

```
import {mapActions} from 'vuex'
export default {
    name: "Dashboard",
    data: () => ({}),
    created() {
        this.checkUserState();
    },
methods: {
    ...mapActions({
        checkUserState: 'auth/setLoggedInState',
    }),
```

I don’t understand how to fix errors I tried many ways I hope for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you learn something new, please check for missing '; , .' etc.
And be sure that you write 'const mutations' not 'const mutation', following the documentation saving hours))

Comment: If the code has syntax errors please point them out directly in your answer to help the author and other readers.